# Spring change the sorting fields' order for mongodb

Tags: spring, mongodb, sorting, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

I try to sort data in mongo by the Spring `Sort` object, with 2 specific fields.
For some reason, Spring changes the order of the 'sorting fields'.

I use Spring and MongoDB data (`MongoTemplate`). I use `findAll()` function for get some records.
In mongo data I have specific index `{ "status": -1, "_id": -1 }`.
I want to sort by this specific index, and for that I added this code for sorting:

```
new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "status").and(new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, 
"_id"));
```

I sort by `status` field, and then by `_id` field (like the index).

### FYI:

I use other indexes and sort by them, and Spring doesn't sort my 'sorting fields':

```
{ "status": -1, "__sort_authors": 1 }

{ "status": -1, "__sort_title": 1 }
```

On these cases the Spring saves the sorting fields' order in the Mongo query:

Query: `{...}, Sort: { "status":-1, "__sort_authors":1 }`

Query: `{...}, Sort: { "status":-1, "__sort_title":1 }`

**The expected mongo query should be:**

> { "foldersIds" : { "$in" : ["project:6s5d4f32sd1f65"] }, "availability" : "PRESENT" }, Fields: { }, **Sort: { "status" : -1, "_id" : -1 }**

**The actual mongo query is:**

> { "foldersIds" : { "$in" : ["project:5c505594e4b0e98a6537ec9d"] }, "availability" : "PRESENT" }, Fields: { }, **Sort: { "_id" : -1, "status" : -1 }**

Maybe it because the `_id` is the primary field?

I want to keep the order of the sorting fields. Any idea how to save the order?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try explicitly setting the order by passing a `List` instead of calling the `and` method. Something like this:

```
ArrayList<Order> orders = new ArrayList<>();
orders.add(new Sort.Order(Sort.Direction.DESC, "status"));
orders.add(new Sort.Order(Sort.Direction.DESC, "_id"));
Sort sort = Sort.by(orders);
```

The reason I suggest this is because the `Sort.and()` method's documentation only specifies it combines the specified sorts, it doesn't specify how or in what order it combines them. Using a `List` should hopefully enforce the ordering that you want.